# Spatial Light Modulator (SLM) phase-only versus amplitude-only modulation

Tags: optics, laser, diffraction

I am reading about the phase-only vs amplitude-only modulation with  Spatial Light Modulators (SLMs). I wonder if there are specialists here who do this for living.

For instance, [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep07441) the authors state that SLMs do phase-only modulation. Well, if I use the [fork grating](https://spookyactionbook.com/2016/04/10/how-to-demonstrate-twisted-light-using-a-laser-pointer/) as a mask, and generate, say, Laguerre-Gauss out of Gauss beam, this is, obviously, phase modulation. But isn't it also amplitude  modulation? The amplitude gets re-distributed so that only a small portion of the initial beam power gets into a particular diffraction order under consideration, can't in be considered an amplitude modulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A phase-only Spatial Light Modulator like the one described in your link consists of an array of liquid crystals. Ideally, these have 100% transmission so that the incident light does *not* lose intensity/power upon absorption. The only effect resulting from the interaction is a phase acquired because of the increased optical path length given by the orientation of the liquid crystal (controlled by a voltage underneath it).

So it is a *phase* modulation because the only quantity that the SLM has control over is the *phase*. 
 In the imaging plane you have a different amplitude distribution, sure, but (ideally) the total power is the same as the input (it is not, because of losses).

An example of *amplitude* modulation is a [Digital Mirror Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_micromirror_device) (DMD) where you have an array of small mirrors that actually chuck light out in some areas of the incident beam, which *controllably* affects the amplitude.

Comment: So I only can do phase modulation by SLMs if I have a cascade, than I modulate by the relative optical path in that cascade... Got it.

Comment: @MsTais ... don't know exactly what you mean by 'cascade.,

Comment: multiple SLM's different distance from a beam splitter. By varying distance between the BBSs and SLMs one can get amplitude and phase modulated at the same time.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I mean "I only can do phase AND AMPLITUDE modulation..." sorry. I see where the confusion came form...

Answer (score 2):

Not really adding much to SuperCiocia's answer, just driving one point home hard.

Ideally the only difference in the light before and after the SLM is that the phase of the light has been modified. No amplitude modulation, only phase. Of course, if you use a lens to Fourier transform the optical pattern directly at the output of the SLM then the Fourier transformed result will have a different amplitude distribution than if there were no phase mask.

That is, changing the phase of an image can change the amplitude distribution of its Fourier transform. This is why and how a phase-only modulator can be useful for, among other things, holographic beam shaping.